# How to check if backup is enabled on azure virtual machine using azure command or virtual machine level flag

Tags: azure

How to check if a backup is enabled on an azure virtual machine using PowerShell or azure command
in my use case, I don't want to go with Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer stuff, looking for any other option available on the virtual machine level for checking backup status of a VM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is pretty much nothing on the `az vm` cli for what you are looking for.

To check directly on the vm level, you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.recoveryservices/Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupStatus?view=azps-3.0.0

Thus you will get the BackedUp property to check if your vm is being backed up.

In type parameter,  you need to use `AzureVM` value. Name and resource group I need not explain.